# Parameter securityEnabledOnly must be valid Boolean value

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get the [groups of a user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/functions-and-actions#getMemberGroups) using [Azure AD Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/#).

With a url similar to *`https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/user_id@company.com/getMemberGroups`* I am getting the following error:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Parameter securityEnabledOnly must be valid Boolean value."
        },
        "date": "2017-09-25T04:26:30",
        "requestId": "f43323c9-97e9-4ef2-813f-57690b2869a8",
        "values": null
    }
}
```

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As shown by the error message , the securityEnabledOnly parameter should be a Boolean value true/false:
[image]